# Views: Use like operator in exposed search filter (Search: Search Terms)

Tags: views

In a view, I am using an exposed filter of keyword search (Search: Search Terms). The default behavior of the filter is to select exact matches. I need to have similar words also selected. For instance when the visitor searches for "paint", she should see "painting" or "painter" too.

Similar to the "LIKE" operator in mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a new filter in views on a field (for example node title), you can set the Operator to `contains` which is the equivalent of SQL `LIKE`.
You can also expose the filter and the operator to the visitor.
If you want to see the SQL query in the preview, check the option *Show the SQL query* in view setting.

Instead of *Search: Search Terms*, use *Global: Combine fields filter*; it will allow you to search multiple fields using the operator you want.