# Wildcard Search in Views

Tags: views

Is there a way to use Wildcards (like *) in Views filters. I do not want to give the user the dropdown with all the operators but use a wildcard.
For example, when he writes *name it will use "ends with", on name* "begins with", on name "contains" and so on. Is there something out there that can do that, or do I have to write it on my own?

Comment: Contains does exactly same thing... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88632/views-use-like-operator-in-exposed-search-filter-search-search-terms

Comment: It does not. it is always working with "like". But if I want to get only the "ends with" or "starts with" items, I just can't get them with "contains" but get all items that contain my search-word. Looks like I have to code that.

Comment: You can try views query alter .. For more info http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76651/how-to-use-hook-views-query-alter-to-modify-where-condition

Answer (score 0):

Rather than filtering on a certain field (and then exposing the filter), try adding a filter of the type 'Search terms'. That uses drupal's search module to search, which has much smarter ways of searching.

[image]

Comment: It seems like I can't use "search terms" in my commerce products view or I can't find it :(